# Is it a normal to make http request on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, i18next, server-side-rendering

I'm using SSR with react and i18next. I don't have a lot experience with Node.js, so the question is:
Is it a normal way to make an external http request in a start of a server script execution and pass all the left server script code into the `then` function of a returned `Promise` instance as a later continuation part of the script.

Server code which is bundled and then is started

`server.js`

```
import express from 'express';
import promiseRequest from 'request-promise';
import i18next from "i18next";
import middleware from "i18next-express-middleware";
import render from './render';

const app = express();

promiseRequest.get('https://api/localization')
  .then(data => {
    i18next.use(middleware.LanguageDetector);
    i18next.init();

    app.use(middleware.handle(i18next));

    app.listen(3000, () =>
      console.log('App is running')
    );

    return app;
  });
```

The reason I go this way is because I need to init i18n based on a response from a server.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here...

Comment: I have a doubt that a server cannot start until request is finished. Or what if this endpoint fails at all.

Comment: You can attach middleware to the express application at any time, you don't have to attach it before the server starts. If the endpoint fails, maybe you should gracefully kill the application? It's not clear what your use-case calls for, but this feels more like a code review than a stack overflow question.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to make an api request to figure out your localization needs? Wouldn't that be a part of the incoming request to your static server (gimme the website in english, french, etc)? I'm unclear about your use case. Are you trying to have several instances of your static server to serve different languages?

A common model I've seen is to have multiple static files pre-generated, per localization, and then serve them up based on the request, ex: have a route that returns the english version when the user makes a request to http://yourwebsite.com/en, the french one at http://yourwebsite.com/fr or http://yourwebsite.fr, etc.

Comment: I need to make 1 request on a server start, which should give me something like that: ['en', 'de'] which I then pass to render function of the App(It should know available languages) and use as options for i18next init(whiteList property, for example).